# Convert JSON object to Scala object dynamically

Tags: json, scala

I am working on a use-case where i am trying to built a web UI interface(using react and play framework) that takes Json/Json string as input and return Scala object that represents given json.

**Input:**

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

**Output:**

```
{SomeObjectName}(1,1,"delectus aut autem", false)
```

Here is my understanding, to get scala object from json we need scala object type.
For example, we need class definition of **MailServer** as shown in this [example](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-scala-object-instance-from-json-string/)

I found one [example](https://transform.tools/json-to-scala-case-class) on how to convert json to case class in react using library: **transform-json-types**. Problem here is this library is in UI. If i have some library like this in scala that would be great but i couldn't find one. So, i am thinking to send generated case class definition from UI to backend as string and then extract case class in backend.

Few questions:

1. Can i extract case class definition from string? If yes, how?
2. Am i going in the right direction?
3. Is there any other way to solve this use-case?

Any help is appreciated. Please point me in right direction.

Comment: So you can't define all of those possible jsons as object on backend side?
Remember if some field is optional in json, it can be defined as Option in scala.

Comment: Yes because user input is in UI.

Comment: From what I understand, you want to handle arbitrary JSON values, thus I would just use `JsObject` from play-json for instance and create a method that look at it and generate a nice string or a case class definition.

Comment: It seems all you need is a JSON library in **Scala**, have you looked at: **circe**, **uJson**,  **play-json**, etc?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, i have looked at some of these libraries. Haven't found any library that suits my requirement. Unless i missed something.

Comment: @Raju and what are your requirements? Converting a JSON to an already defined case class? Any of those can do that and is probably one of the first examples. - Or do. You need to manipulate an arbitrary JSON? Then AFAIK most of them define a generic `JSON` type and provide some way to traverse it; at least I know **circe** can. - Or do you want to define case classes at runtime? Well  that is not longer the responsability of a JSON library, but also something that is a bad a idea and you my better assume is not possible.

Comment: @Luis. In short , I want to convert json to scala without explicitly providing case class definition.

Comment: @Raju and what does _"Scala"_ mean in your case? Like, what do you even expect the output to be? How do you expect to use that output? As Dima said, you either need to redesign your program or you need to operate on a dynamic format; the latter would be using the `JSON` datatype of any of the mentioned libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, that even if you had a way to create (or somehow infer an existing definition) a case class on the fly, you wouldn't really be able to do much with it:

```
    val foo = magicLibrary.readJson(fooJsonString)
```

What type is `foo` above? It's gotta be `Any` (or, maybe, `AnyRef`). Even if `magicLibrary` had a (magic) way of figuring out an constructing an actual class from given json, there is no way you can use that type downstream, because it is not going to be known at compile time.

The only thing you could do with that result is print it out, or, perhaps, convert back to json. But you already have json, so that's not useful.

Long story short, unless I completely misunderstood what you are asking, there is no library like this, and if there was one, it would not be of much use anyway.

What you can do in this case is just parse the the input into a `Map[String, Any]` using one of the standard json libraries ... that may or may not be useful, depending on what it is you actually want to do with the result.

Better yet, rework your API to deal with actual known types.